# Can I publish a collection of poetry that alludes to other authors such as Shakespeare and Wordsworth without violating copyright?

Tags: copyright, self-publishing, legal, poetry

I am a teacher.  My students want to self publish their work as a collection of poetry and short stories.
Some of their assignments were to allude to other works and authors—like Wordsworth or Shakespeare’s sonnets.

Would I be able to include the inspirational texts, without violating copyright laws?

I don’t want to “not” include them if they “should” be included. And I don’t want to break any copyright laws either.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Does that answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain#Expiration_of_copyright ?

Comment: Thank you!!!  I really appreciate uou taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shakespeare's works will be in the public domain. For other authors, you'll probably need to research each one. @user482877's comment gives you a good [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain#Expiration_of_copyright) for understanding how it works.

You'll want to check each one. If something is under copyright, contacting the copyright holder to ask for permission (in writing) is very appropriate. I suspect a lot of them would give their permission for a student publication.

Comment: Thank you!!! So grateful for your input!

Comment: @Sgriggs Be careful: While Shakespeare's works are most certainly in the public domain, recent editions of his works may not be. The work of a scholarly editor who prepares an old text for a new publication may be protected by copyright itself. If you want to use a public domain work, make sure you cite it from a public domain publication or you get written permission from the publisher.